# while loop won't break, python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Soo i have this problem that the while loop just  wont break:

```
print 'Enter your chosen email below!'
def valid_email(mail):
    email = mail[-len('@gmail.com'):len(mail)]
    failled = mail[0:-len('@gmail.com')]
    condition = True
    while condition:
        for a in mail:
           if a == ' ':
                print 'Try again'
                condition = False

        if email == '@gmail.com':
            print 'You have succesfully logged in our website!'
            break
        else:
            print 'Did you mean ' + failled + 'gmail.com'
        break

print valid_email('eq@gmai l.com')
```

i get output:

```
Enter your chosen email below!
Try again
Did you mean eq@gmail.com
```

i expected:

```
Enter your chosen email below!
Try again
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your loop will only break when it checks the condition, which is at the start of each iteration. Since you are setting `condition = False` in the middle of your loop, the code below it is still run

Comment: You either need to `break` instead of `condition = False` or check `if condition == True` and then execute the if checks

Comment: break dosen't work for me ,if statement works just fine, but i still have trouble understanding how my current code deosent work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

"The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the smallest enclosing for or while loop."

You are breaking out of the for loop, not the while loop. I think this does what you want:

```
print 'Enter your chosen email below!'
def valid_email(mail):
    email = mail[-len('@gmail.com'):len(mail)]
    failled = mail[0:-len('@gmail.com')]

    if ' ' in mail:
        print 'Try again'

    if email == '@gmail.com':
        print 'You have succesfully logged in our website!'
    else:
        print 'Did you mean ' + failled + 'gmail.com'

print valid_email('eq@gmai l.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to remove spaces, then I recommend using str.replace(" ","") (where str = the email address)

Comment: I want if the user writes the invalid adress, error will pop up.:P

Answer (score 0):

Try using `in` instead of the for loop:

```
if ' ' in email:
    break
```

When you break in the `for` loop, you are only breaking that loop, not the `while` loop.